# C# Selenium Testing - How to press the enter/return key if there's no identifier?

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Setting up tests to run on Firefox and I am constantly getting prompted to give details which will not allow the tests to run efficiently.

I have username and password saved in but need to find a way to press the enter key to get through to the actual test.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlJ0U.png

Comment: Can you give an example?
Is this prompt in the browser?

Comment: @JamieRees I attached a picture example as a temporary answer

Comment: @EoinRockall do you have the HTML of the pop-up?

Comment: No, there's no HTML, no identifiers, nothing

Comment: ^ There are several options in that link

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic authentication. To bypass authentication change url to following format, replace "username" with yours, "password" with yours and "url" with yours :

```
https://username:password@url
```

Some additional info you can find [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12892/how-to-send-basic-authentication-headers-in-selenium).

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work

Comment: @EoinRockall can you share your code?